# please i need help, i am new to react-native-reanimated, i am having the following error

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo, react-native-reanimated

Expected 3-4 arguments, but got 2.ts(2554) react-native-reanimated.d.ts(383, 7): An argument for 'output' was not provided.

```
const translateX = Animated.interpolate(props.progress, {
inputRange: [0, 0.5, 0.7, 0.8, 1],
outputRange: [-100, -85, -70, -45, 0],
```

});re

Comment: please provide more information like the version of the library. Have you followed the documentation and the examples there?

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because you're using the interpolate definition from reanimated 1 whereas typescript is recognizing the interpolate definition of reanimated 2. Change interpolate to interpolateNode.

Refer to the following link: 
https://docs.swmansion.com/react-native-reanimated/docs/2.3.0-alpha.2/migration/#1-interpolate-renamed-to-interpolatenode